# SQL SERVER 2005 getting average usages for a year split into 30 day periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table "UserId", "Date", "Application" that records the date and time a user used an application I have manged to split it by month into average usage for the past year. However I have been asked to split in on 30 day billing periods instead of months. Can anyone please help in how I can split the data efficently into a table thats shows for each Application and each 30 days the average number of users.

This is the query for splitting by month an application

```
select Month(UsageLog.[Date]) as [Month], Year(UsageLog.[Date]) as [Year],
(Count(UsageLog.UserName)/COUNT(Distinct UsageLog.[Date])) as NumUsers,
UsageLog.Application
From Licensing.dbo.Table_UsageLog 
where UsageLog.[Date] > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GetDate())
Group By Month(UsageLog.[Date]), Year(UsageLog.[Date]), UsageLog.Application
```

Comment: How are your 30 day billing periods defined--Is it different for each user based on when they signed up? If user A signed up 1/1/2013 and user B signed up 1/15/2013 would their billing periods extend to 2/1/2013 and 2/15/2013 respectively?

Comment: So what is wrong with the query above?

Comment: Good question the brief is in 30 day periods from a year ago from the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct IF you have Months in TWO years (let say is middle of the year )you can not have ORDER!!!!

You must CAST as MM-YYYY or use my suggest with + '-' +

try this

```
select Month(UsageLog.[Date])   + '-' + Year(UsageLog.[Date]) as MonthYear ,
  Count(UsageLog.Application ) as NumUsers,
 UsageLog.Application
 From Licensing.dbo.Table_UsageLog 
 where UsageLog.[Date] > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GetDate())
 Group By  Month(UsageLog.[Date])   + '-' + Year(UsageLog.[Date]) , UsageLog.Application
 order by  Month(UsageLog.[Date])   + '-' + Year(UsageLog.[Date]) DESC
```

You can use it with  order by  Month(UsageLog.[Date])   + '-' + Year(UsageLog.[Date])

Comment: that gives monthyears with values like 2025 and the averages look wrong, something not right there

Comment: You are COUNTING in this month 12-2013  CNT UsageLog.Application
; YOU NEED TO CAST  your UsageLog.Application
the name must be FIXED; LOOK first GROUP BY UsageLog.Application how many rows is giving this must work first

Comment: just chcked in excel averages are working, note you dropped the calculation that made them averages I dont know if that made a difference?